# toggle show and hide not working

Tags: jquery

i am new to jquery, I was trying this FAQ exercise from A jquery book, but it only shows the faq answer when clicked and when we click it again it is suposed to hide but it doesn't

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dynamicFaq();
});

   function dynamicFaq() {
        $('dd').hide();
        $('dt').bind('click', function(){
            $(this).next().show();
        });
        $('dt').bind('click', function(){
            $(this).next().toggle();
        });
   }
```

Thank you all.
The books exercise was this="6. Now we've moved from the question to the answer. Now all that's left to do is show
the answer:

```
$('dt').bind('click', function(){
$(this).next().show();
});
```

7. Don't forget that our dynamicFaq function won't do anything until we call it. Call
   the dynamicFaq function inside your document ready statement:

   $(document).ready(function(){
   dynamicFaq();
   });
8. Now, if we load the page in the browser, you can see that all of our answers are
   hidden until we click on the question. This is nice and useful, but it would be even
   nicer if the site visitor could hide the answer again when they're done reading it to
   get it out of their way. Luckily, this is such a common task, jQuery makes this very
   easy for us. All we have to do is replace our call to the .show() method with a call
   to the .toggle() method as follows:

   $('dt').bind('click', function(){
   $(this).next().toggle();
   });"

Answer (score 0):

```
 function dynamicFaq() {
        $('dd').hide();
        $('dt').bind('click', function(){
            $(this).next().show();//showing
        });
        $('dt').bind('click', function(){
            $(this).next().toggle();//hiding
        });
   }
```

So, never gonna show.

Just do this way:

```
 function dynamicFaq() {
        $('dd').hide();
        $('dt').bind('click', function(){
            $(this).next().toggle();//hide or show
        });
   }
```

Comment: Ahhhhh! it was so simple, Thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('dd').hide();
    $('dt').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just bind the element inside $(document).ready() , no need to call a function again.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('dd').hide();
    $('dt').click(function() {
        $('dd').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply too. That also works bu it shows all of the answers at the same time.

Comment: Oh I see, just don't understand your $(this).next() at first as didn't see html part. Great that it works right now ;)